# return(q * log(..)) in a function returns error

Tags: r

I'm building a function that uses a variable called q in the calling code and returns q * log(.. some number .. ). 
When creating this function in a session it works perfectly but when creating a package with this function after loading the package in another session it doesn't work. Here is a simplified example

In R:

```
>myfunc <- function() return(q * log(2.0))
>q=1.0
>myfunc()
[1] 1.386294
>package.skeleton(list=c("myfunc"),name="mypckg")
```

after building and installing package again in R

```
> library(mypckg)
> q = 3.0
> myfunc()
Erreur dans q * log(2) : argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire
```

If I modify the name of the variable from q to qq or any other name everything works perfectly.

Can anyone explain what is happening. Is q some reserved name is this some known bug in R ?

Comment: `q` is the function to terminate the current R session

Comment: Don’t write `return(…)` if that’s the only return path in the function. R is a functional language, just write `function () q * log(2.0)`

Comment: Sorry whith or without return the bug is still there !!

Comment: @KonradRudolph while true, it's good coding practice to use a `return` statement to make it clear what's being returned, not  to mention avoiding accidentally returning something undesired if somethings added to the function body.

Comment: @Carl “it's good coding practice to use a `return` statement”. No. I disagree. It goes counter the design of R as a functional language where everything is an expression. It’s a form of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @ Jörg: I thought that R triggers the q function only when it is called explicitely with q(), and didn't think that it would be some reserved name !!!

Comment: @mike: You thought wrong. Try renaming your object to 'qqqqq' and see what error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrap your function inside a package, it lives in another environment than your remaining code which includes the package. As a consequence, `myfunc` is searching a different set of environments for `q`, and instead of your variable, it finds `base::q`, which is a function.

The solution is not to access global variables like that in a function. Instead, use parameters:

```
myfunc <- function (q) q * log(2.0)
```

Comment: To clarify: `R` interprets a function sans the parentheses as a request to print the function. So the `myfunc` "sees"  `function (save = "default", status = 0, runLast = TRUE) 
.Call("RappQuit", save, status, runLast)
<environment: 0x100fe19f0> * log(2.0)` and barfs on that text.

Comment: Konrad: I know that, the example is just a simplified one. My original function has as argument a vector of parameters that needs to be modified by nlminb that works only with one argument functions so there is no place for a function with two arguments myfunc(param, q) in such situations. In this case my functions need to access global variables ...

Comment: @Carl Where does the character string conversion come from? I don’t think that’s happening here: `q` isn’t in a context where such a conversion would happen, and in fact the same error would occur even without that conversion: for instance, try `list() * 2` to get the same error. `*` is simply not defined for non-numeric arguments.

Comment: @mike No, they *don’t* need to access global variables. Rewrite this, it’s generally seen as unacceptably bad design to have packages share variables in this manner. Use classes or other mechanisms of sharing state, but using global variables doesn’t work.

Comment: @Carl it is probably not elegant but it worked very fine for me the original more complex function that takes one argument myfunc(param) and uses global variables called x, n, etc.  is then used in nlminb(start=..., myfunc, lower .., upper ...) to find optimal param ...

Comment: @Carl In fact, I just checked it since I was curious. It doesn’t “interpret a function sans the parentheses as a request to print the function”. Instead, it passes the function as-is to `*`, which in turn calls `.Primitive('*')` which in turn calls `do_arith` in the C code which, finally, calls `R_binary`. [And there, finally](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3ab4effe3f9822045392468b55d7ef9215f8fe91/src/main/arithmetic.c#L584) it checks whether its argument is numeric and, failing that, reports an error.

Comment: Konrad and @Carl, what I learned from this discussion is that when using global variables in functions I should avoid to use names that might conflict with function names in the base package.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Thanks for doing the deep check on what actually happened to `q` .  But in the end, it wasn't numeric :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a 'q'-value to be available when a function is re-used,  you had two options: use it in the argument list or define it in the function body so it gets kept.

```
myfunc <- function(q=1.0) return(q * log(2.0))
myfunc()
```

Or:

```
myfunc <- function() {q<-1.0; q * log(2.0) }  # less flexible definition of q
myfunc()
```

Jörg Mäder's comment is pointing out that error message indicates that it did find 'q', just not in the list of named data-objects, but rather in the list of named-functions.

Comment: @Jorg: q comes from data that are read in the main script and it is a vector whose size I don't know in advance. Its not clear to me how this can help ...

Comment: What's wrong with passing 'q' to the function via its argument list?

Comment: As I already commented to another answer: My original function (which is more complex) has as argument a vector of parameters that needs to be modified by nlminb that works only with one argument functions so there is no place for a function with two arguments myfunc(param, q) in such situations. In this case my functions need to access global variables ..

Comment: You should put the needed information in the question, That is what the editing button is for.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean should i have sad that my original function is not myfunction() but in fact myfunction(params) which is a vector and needs to be optimized by nlminb ??

Comment: And you should have made clear how you were going to pass data to `nlminb`.